# Streaming JSON data

Tags: android, web-services, node.js

I need to load pins to a map (Google Maps Android API v2) as the user changes its location, but I wanted to load them "smoothly" instead of having to wait for the entire result set being downloaded to add all pins at once.

Is there any web service or a different technology that allows me to read data (like JSON) from the server as a stream and asynchronously add pins to the map?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm assuming you're in control of the server? If that is so, why not simply use `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` and write out pieces of JSON?

Comment: @NitzanShaked as this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16736233/web-api-as-a-proxy-and-chunked-transfer-encoding) points, the HttpClient will de-chunk the message, thus it will wait for the entire response to be processed so it can add pins to the map.

Comment: @JulianoNunesSilvaOliveira: that's a detail of a specific HTTP client. Doesn't your client (on android presumably) have an `onData()` or `bufferReceived` event?

Comment: I found that Volley http library has an `onResponse` event. I'll try it when I get home. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of two ways of approaching this for asynchronously loading google points

1. Using Services and Broadcasts, Using an IntentService (or a Service class) to parse the JSON and broadcasting the results as and when you get results in your parsing. Have a Broadcast Receiver which would be listening to these broadcasts. In the onHandle method of your broadcast receiver you could keep creating new markers. ([Tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-fundamentals-intentservice-basics/))
2. Using [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and on your onProgressUpdate method you could keep passing your json parse results and that could keep updating the maps.

As for parsing of JSON I believe you can just use any parsing techniques to get an input stream.

I think I would suggest the first approach as that would be more fluid and gives you more control if you are using multi-threading.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

[Oboe.js](http://github.com/jimhigson/oboe.js) is a tool for reading of JSON as it arrives. Other projects have used it to load a lot of points into a Google map but show them one at a time.

disclaimer: it is my project.