# Serving data with "transfer-encoding: chunked" on an ApiController in C#' WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, chunked-encoding

I need to serve **chunked transfer** encoding data using an **ApiController**. Because I do not have access to the **HttpContext** or the **HttpRequest**, I'm a bit lost as to where to write to the response and where to flush it.

The setup looks like:

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
   [Route("testing")]
   [HttpGet]
   public string Get()
   {
       ...
       return <response object ot HttpResponseMessage
   }
}
```

I guess I might be using the wrong base classes/framework/concept? 
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You *do* have access to the Context and the Request. You need access to the Response though:

```
public string Get()
{
    ActionContext.Response.Headers.TransferEncodingChunked = true;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, but you need to be careful because there is a bug in certain versions of the framework when using chunking with proxies.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16736233/web-api-as-a-proxy-and-chunked-transfer-encoding and https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/1124 .  This was apparently fixed in the most recent version, but at least one person is reporting the problem still exists..  Not sure about ASP.NET 5 though.

Comment: I'm actually getting a null `ActionContext.Response`. I can however create a new HttpResponseMessage and return it